# SOQL: How to query records based on CreatedDate?

Tags: apex, soql, sosl

From the opportunity object, using SOQL, I want to query records which have been created x days (say 30 days) before today. I have written the following code:

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Name FROM Opportunity WHERE (Today() - CreatedDate) = 30];
```

But it shows an error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify date values or date literals in WHERE clauses to filter SOQL query results. Dates represent a specific day or time, while date literals represent a relative range of time, such as last month, this week, or next year.

Refer the [Date Formats and Date Literals in WHERE Clauses](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)

LAST_N_DAYS:n

> For the number `n` provided, starts with the current day and continues
> for the past `n` days.

Try with below query.

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Name FROM Opportunity where WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:30]
```

Comment: The explanation is as important as the answer.

Comment: edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is what [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) are for.

Specifically, `N_DAYS_AGO:<integer>`

So instead of

```
WHERE (Today() - CreatedDate) = 30
```

You want

```
WHERE CreatedDate = N_DAYS_AGO:30
```